# About compile ADT from Android source code

Tags: android, adt, android-source

When I try to compile ADT through Android source code,I used these command:

$sdk/eclipse/scripts/build_adt.sh /home

but when I press enter,terminal exit right away。

who can tell me why??thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `build_adt.sh` script you can see in the first few lines it is checking the length of the arguments you have provided to the script.

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <out_dir> <dest_dir> <build_number>" > /dev/stderr
  echo "Given arguments: $*" > /dev/stderr
  exit 1
fi
```

You are only providing a single argument of `/home` when the script is expecting three arguments `<out_dir>`, `<dest_dir>` and `<build_number>` in that order. The script will exit without doing anything if you have not provided it the three arguments it's expecting.